# decode Special Character in Angular + Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, angularjs, character-encoding

My Object label is `D & B Company`, this is stored in a list at some place

When it comes to visualforce page in angular code, it is showing `D&amp;B Company`

How can handle such type of special character in angular, I tried escape ="false"
but no result

```
function(result, event) {
                    $scope.Data =  result;
                    $scope.$apply();

                    angular.forEach($scope.Data, function(value, key){
                        if(value.objApiName == 'DatacloudDandBCompany')
                        {
                            var t = value.objLabel;

                        console.log("username is ::" + decodeURIComponent(t)); 
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for decode your url

```
your_url = decodeURIComponent(your_url);
your_url  = decodeURI(your_url );
```

Use this for encode url

```
your_url = encodeURIComponent(your_url);
your_url  = encodeURI(your_url );
```

It may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not escaping the output of your RemoteAction method - several html chars are encoded as HTML entities when they are sent this way - but you can turn this off like so:

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    '{!$RemoteAction.YourClass.yourMethod}',
    someParam, 
    function(result, event){
        //... your stuff
    }, 
    {escape: true}
);
```

(it's the last parameter of the call - `{escape : true}` that you want)